# this keyword is not working in $.each array - IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set **srcset** value of an image to **src** attribute using $.each in jquery. That is working fine in chrome & Firefox and it returns ***undefined*** always in IE which therefore breaking my page in IE11. below is my code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('img[srcset]');
  $.each(img,function(){
  this.src = this.srcset;
  });
});
```

Can someone help in resolving this issue. I see sometimes **img** in $.each also goes undefined. But when i check before $.each execution, img shows all 32 elements. Confused. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('srcset'));`

Comment: Try `this.src = this.getAttribute('srcset');`

Comment: I tried even $(this).srcset as well. Tried even with for loop in pure javascript by checking img[i].srcset. This also returns undefined.

Comment: Or better `$('img[srcset]').attr('src', function() {
    return $(this).attr('srcset');
});`

Comment: Ok let me try @Tushar

Comment: `$(this).srcset` will not work, you're mixing jQuery with JS. Use `$(this).attr('srcset')`

Comment: @Tushar - Is there any way to stop executing the javascript code in IE browser?? My Javascript file(.js) has the above code this needs to be executed only in chrome & firefox and not in IE. Any solution for this??